# Client secret not provided in request [unauthorized_client]

Tags: keycloak

Here what i tried login to server where keyclock deploy and use the below directory `/keycloak/bin/`
and run following command

```
 ./kcadm.sh config credentials --server https://<IP ADRESS>:8666/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin
```

But this command throw error.

> Client secret not provided in request [unauthorized_client]

Why client information is required ? I have to do this through Admin CLI

1. Login into the keycloak
2. Create a New realm
3. Create User and userGroup.

So according to me in this case client secret or any such information not require but admin-cli command complaining about same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution of the above problem.After installation the keycloak .Keycloak will by default create few clients(`account,admin-cli,broker,master-realm,security-admin-console`) and in these all clients `admin-cli` will be come with `access-type=public` So if you are trying to login through keycloak u have to fire below command from `/keycloak/bin` directory

```
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server https://<IP ADDRESS>:8666/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin --client admin-cli
```

As i am using `https` you may get the below error as well

> Failed to send request - sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

To overcome this issue please generate the certificate and put inside `/keycloak/security/ssl` folder and then fire this command

```
kcadm.sh config truststore --trustpass $PASSWORD ~/.keycloak/truststore.jks
```

Now question how to create the realm then after login through `admin-cli` client use below command

```
./kcadm.sh create realms -s realm=demorealm -s enabled=true
```

Comment: In case you have created a certificate elsewhere run this to import it: `keytool -import -noprompt -storepass $PASSWORD -keystore ~/.keycloak/truststore.jks -file server.crt`